# stop only click event bubbling but allow blur in Angular

Tags: angular, events

I am facing an issue that I use

```
(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
```

to prevent the event bubbling, it stops all events but I would like to allow blur. Is there any way to do it?

```
<cell-editor
      
    (valueChanged)="quantityChanged($event, element)"
    (focusedIn)="focusedIn(element, editableCells.Checked)"
    (resetChanges)="resetChanges()"
    (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
            >
</g3-cell-editor>
```

Comment: Your opening and closing tags are not the same. And what do you mean blur isn't allowed? On the cell-editor? Somewhere inside or outside? (IIRC if you want a (blur) on your component you would have to implement it)

Answer (score 0):

[ng-event-plugins](https://github.com/Tinkoff/ng-event-plugins) is a neat library that allows you to do that !

`<div (click.stop)="onClick()">Clicks on this DIV will not bubble up</div>`